# PHP MailScript - Unable to receive email

Tags: php, email, forms

For some reason i cant receive any email from my submit form - is there a problem with my formmail script?

```
<form action="contact_process.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="three">
  <legend><strong>Form</strong></legend>
  <fieldset>
<p>
<label for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>
<label for="email">Your Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email"></p>

<p>
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject"></p>

<p>
<label for="EnquiryType">Enquiry Type</label>
<select type="text" name="EnquiryType">
  <option value="general">General</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select></p>

<p>
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea type="text" name="message" class="msg"></textarea></p>

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">

</form>
```

**contact_process.php**

```
<?php
    # bool has_injection (String $var, [String $var, ...])
    function has_injection () {
        $values = func_get_args();
        for ($i=0, $count=func_num_args(); $i<$count; $i++) {
            if ( stristr($values[$i], "%0A") || stristr($values[$i], "%0D") || stristr($values[$i], "\\r") || stristr($values[$i], "\\n") 
                || stristr($values[$i], "Bcc") || stristr($values[$i], "Content-Type") ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    $error = '';
    if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) {
        # The form has been submitted
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $EnquiryType = $_POST['EnquiryType'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

        if ($name && $email && $subject && $EnquiryType && $message) {
            if (has_injection($name, $email, $subject, $EnquiryType, $message)) {
                # You've got another spammer at work here
                $error = 'No spamming';
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                # It's safe to send the message
                mail('my@email.com', $subject, $message, $EnquiryType, $message,"From: $name <$email>");
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = 'Please fill in all the forms';
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: may be. it's hard to tell by *watching* a code. To find a problem one have to **run** it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u send 6 parameters..
i checked that and i get elow error

```
mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\parixan\contact_process.php on line 31
```

see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

#### update

```
$message = $_POST['EnquiryType']."\r\n".$_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: $name <$email>' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: $name <$email>' . "\r\n" ;
```

then use

```
mail('my@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty good PHP email script that sends. I've been programming a website of my own (PHP, HTML) and I'm trying to find a way to receive emails. I've heard about POP3, and others but I can't ever find much on them.

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "This email was sent from a no-reply email service. \n\n $message";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Hope that helps ^^